# rxjs: bindCallback returns a bad Observable signature

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using [`bindCallBack`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) in order to transform a `f(x, callback)` to an `Observable<Action>`. Where `f(x, callback)` is:

```
f(
   data: StripeCardTokenData,
   responseHandler: 
   (
      status: number,
      response: StripeCardTokenResponse
   ) => void
): void;
```

So, `f` is [`Stripe.card.createToken`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/555ea54770b8576162e761e344de969d6e960869/stripe/index.d.ts#L78).

where `StripeCardTokenResponse` is:

```
interface StripeTokenResponse {
    id: string;
    client_ip: string;
    created: number;
    livemode: boolean;
    object: string;
    type: string;
    used: boolean;
    error?: StripeError;
}
```

By other hand, I'm using an `Observable<Action>` where `Action` is:

```
export interface Action {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
}
```

So, I've declared an `Observable<Action>` on `actions$`:

```
this.actions$
    .ofType('ADD_SOURCE')
    .switchMap(
      (action: Action) => {
        ((((1))))
    );
```

So, on `((((1))))` I need to call `Stripe.card.createToken(data, callback)` and according to `callback(status, response)`'s `response.error` I need to return an `(Observable.of(<Action>{ type: 'ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS' }))` or an `(Observable.of(<Action>{ type: 'ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS' }))`.

Nevertheless, I'm getting some issues.

First of all, I need to create the callback observable:

```
var callback = Observable.bindCallback(Stripe.card.createToken);
```

Nevertheless, typescript is telling me that `callback` is:

```
(local var) callback: (v1: StripeCardTokenData) => Observable<number>
```

So, `callback` is an `Observable<number>`. Where is `response: StripeCardTokenResponse` in order to deal with it?

I don't know if I've explained it so well. I'm really struggling with that but I don't quite figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindCallback` can be tricky. It's all down to TypeScript inferring the types and attempting to match one of [the numerous `bindCallback` signatures](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.2.0/src/observable/BoundCallbackObservable.ts#L18-L34).

If your `callback` variable is `(v1: StripeCardTokenData) => Observable<number>`, TypeScript appears to have matched the function with this signature:

```ts
static create<T, R>(
  callbackFunc: (v1: T, callback: (result: R) => any) => any,
  selector?: void,
  scheduler?: IScheduler
): (v1: T) => Observable<R>;
```

The callback will have been wired up correctly, but to get access to the the `response` parameter, you need to specify a selector:

```ts
var callback = Observable.bindCallback(
  Stripe.card.createToken,
  (status: number, response: StripeCardTokenResponse) => ({ status, response })
);
```

I would recommend being explicit with the callback parameter types (as above) - otherwise, they will be typed as `any`.

With the selector specified, your `callback` variable should have the following type:

```ts
(v1: StripeCardTokenData) => Observable<{ status: number; response: StripeCardTokenResponse; }>
```

And you would use it something like this:

```ts
this.actions$
  .ofType('ADD_SOURCE')
  .switchMap(
    (action: Action) => {
      var callback = Observable.bindCallback(
        Stripe.card.createToken,
        (status: number, response: StripeCardTokenResponse) => ({ status, response })
      );
      return callback(action.payload/* or whatever */)
        .map(({ status, response }) => {
          var result: Action;
          if (response.error) {
            result = { type: "ADD_SOURCE_ERROR" };
          } else {
            result = { type: "ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS" };
          }
          return result;
        });
    }
  );
```

I'm not familiar with the Stripe API, so it's not clear whether or not `Stripe.card.createToken` needs to be bound to `Stripe.card`. If that is the case, I would recommend not using `Function.prototype.bind`, as it returns `any` and that will prevent TypeScript inferring types for `bindCallback`. Instead, you could use an arrow function:

```ts
var callback = Observable.bindCallback(
  (
    data: StripeCardTokenData,
    responseHandler: (status: number, response: StripeCardTokenResponse) => void
  ) => Stripe.card.createToken(data, responseHandler),
  (status: number, response: StripeCardTokenResponse) => ({ status, response })
);
```